# Asp.net mvc child controller reference base controller's property cause request blocking

Tags: asp.net-mvc

There's a property in Base controller:

```
        public bool IsPost
        {
            get
            {
                if (Request.HttpMethod.Equals("POST", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
```

When reference this property in other child controllers, it will block subsequent rquest until previous request end.
For example:
ControllerA and ControllerB both inherits from BaseController, and referenced IsPost property in Index action like this:

```
if (IsPost)
{
}
```

When call ControllerA.Index and then ControllerB.Index, ControllerB.Index will be blocking until ControllerA.Index finish execute. If I remove IsPost reference, then it will not be blocked.
Fix this is simple, but I want to know why cause the blocking?

Comment: Forget about why coding like this, this is a legacy project. It's a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!! It's concurrent session locking.